# Why does method show as deprecated in AS

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following code. Why is the second `stopForeground` highlighted as a deprecation warning in Android Studio ( Electric Eeel | 2022.1.1)?

```
class FooService : android.app.Service() {
    fun bar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE)
        } else {
            stopForeground(true) // This line shows as deprecated 
        }
     }
}
```

I'm using `compileSdk 33` and  `minSdk 21`  `targetSdk 33` and have Android SDK Build-Tools `34-rc1` installed.

Comment: use `ServiceCompat.stopForeground(this, ServiceCompat.STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE)` ... and google sometimes f..up lint ... fx I've test your code in java code and lint doesn't highlighted ... maybe it depends on build tools used (i'm using 33.0.2)

Comment: could you provide compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from your build ? as I wrote with 33, '33.0.2', 22, 33 and java instead kotlin this code doesn't  causing highligh

Comment: To have more info about your code please post where you call this code (Activity or Service) and what @Selvin said about the minSdk, compileSdkVersion, etc...

Comment: If you try to build or run the project what's the error you get? Have you tried the clean and restart option?

Comment: Add a screenshot of the error or why it is displayed as red please we need more information about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `stopForeground` of `ServiceCompat`, following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#stopForeground(boolean)) you need to change the `stopForeground(Boolean)` and pass either `STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE` or `STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH` explicitly instead. Depending on your `compileSDK` it will complain or not, if you have `compileSDK 33` is going to complain since in the new api version they've changed the signature of that method.

From source code of `ServiceCompat` you are trying to use this `stopForeground`, you should pass a `Service` and a `flag`

```
    public static void stopForeground(@NonNull Service service, @StopForegroundFlags int flags) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            Api24Impl.stopForeground(service, flags);
        } else {
            service.stopForeground((flags & ServiceCompat.STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE) != 0);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(24)
    static class Api24Impl {
        private Api24Impl() {
            // This class is not instantiable.
        }

        @DoNotInline
        static void stopForeground(Service service, int flags) {
            service.stopForeground(flags);
        }
    }
```

Internally they use this `stopForeground`

```
    @Deprecated
    public final void stopForeground(boolean removeNotification) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public final void stopForeground(int notificationBehavior) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
```

So, try to use the import of `import androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat.stopForeground` and check if the error persists.

In case you are doing this code inside a `Service` what you should see is the `deprecation` warning as follows

[image]

Try to `Invalidate cache and restart` to see that there's not an IDE problem.

Comment: *you need to change the stopForeground(Boolean) and pass either STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE* he can't because his `minSdkVersion` is lower than 24 and there is no `stopForeground(int)`  ... and lint SHOULD NOT complain about this as he is doing `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N` check ... **so it's prolly a bug in lint** ... `compileSDK 33` doesn't matter lint should take `minSdkVersion` in account

Comment: The check is not necessary since inside of the `stopForeground` it does the check, and if he has the minSdk let's say 23 and targetSdk to 33, the method from ServiceCompat.stopForeground needs a service and a flag

Comment: You didn't wrote about ServiceCompat in an answer and he is not using it... He calls this from own service

Comment: ServiceCompat uses a Service method

Comment: @Selvin, well I've edited the answer with some data..

Comment: While it's providing solution to not show highlight(fair enough) -  still it doesn't answer to the question: `Why does method show ... highlight?` when it should not

Comment: Yes, that's what I've asked in the comments above, we need more information to check where this code is highlighted, otherwise it's kinda hard to check why.

Comment: I've added more info about the build environment to the question.

Comment: @Selvin & Skizo-ozᴉʞS ツ  I'm sorry for wasting your time...it isn't an error but a deprecation warning; I realized I'd called  an error but it is just a deprecation warning.  Thus  my question was why is a deprecation warning shown here - given that it's good code. And I guess the answer is that it's highlighted exactly because it is deprecated.

Comment: @Ewan That's what is on my answer, shall you mark as a correct my answer and upvote?

Answer (score 0):

The line is highlighted as deprecated because it **is** deprecated.

Whilst this is true, it seems strange to me to highlight this in a way that makes it look like an error or something to be avoided. This code is the standard of handling deprecated methods and so perhaps should not be highlighted in a way that makes it *look* like an error...the deprecated line only runs on api levels for which it wasn't deprecated.